# How do you use the new Markdown to insert images?

Tags: support

Okay, so I wanted to edit and insert an image for someone. I assumed it would be easy to rewrite the Markdown. Until I found out that the Markdown has changed. So how do I write it now?
Also, the help UI has outdated documentation on how to write Markdown for images.
[image]

Comment: What markdown code were you using to insert the image that was not working?

Comment: I was editing ```[blah][1]``` into ```![blah][1]```, then I tried using ```![blah](link)```.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't *substantially* different and the UI in the text box still helps when you need

[image: annotated image of something I screenshotted of SO blog for some reason]

Can be generated by

`[![annotated image of something I screenshotted of SO blog for some reason][1]][1]`

`[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWNyx.png`